# what's the meaning of this: _Pragma("clang assume_nonnull begin")

Tags: objective-c, clang, llvm

After I read some Objective-c code, I found this sentence is above the interface, can someone tell me the meaning, or it is thankful to give some tutorials about clang, thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

In newer versions of the Objective-C compiler (clang), parameters, return values, variables, and properties can be defined as allowing or not null values.

This is typically done for each pointer in a declaration by adding the `_Nullable` or `_Nonnull` attribute:

```
int fetch(int * _Nonnull ptr);
```

This means you can't pass `nil` to the `fetch` function.

There are times where you might want every (or most) pointer to be non-null, for example. It gets tedious having to add `_Nonnull` to every pointer in the header file. To make this easier, you can add the pragma at the start of the file and the corresponding end pragma at the end. This will default all pointers to being non-null. If you then need one or two to be nullable, you can add `_Nullable` to just those pointers.

In iOS and macOS you can use `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` and `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END` instead of `_Pragma("clang assume_nonnull begin")` and `_Pragma("clang assume_nonnull end")`.

Of course there are also "nullable" versions too if you want everything to default to nullable instead of non-null.

You can read more about clang and the nullability attributes at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#nullability-attributes